# Revo 3610 not doing HDMI handshake

Tags: linux, hdmi, kodi, acer-revo

I am having a problem with my Revo 3610 which is connected to my TV via HDMI.

For some reason it will not do the HDMI handshake with the TV, so my TV does not think that there is anything in the HDMIport.

I have tested the TV and it works fine with my laptop and DVD player.

It does work sometimes, but this time it's failed for two days in a row. I've tried rebooting and turning the TV off and on, but nothing helps.

I can trick the TV to listen to the HDMI by connecting with my laptop and then changing the HDMI back to my revo; this results in the image going through nicely but there is a big fat "Check signal cable." message on the screen.

I have also tried changing the resolution in the revo but this does not help either.

Has anyone else had this problem before, and if so how did you fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing the DisplayDevice via /etc/X11/xorg.conf.  It may be initializing only the VGA and ignoring the HDMI port.  On my Zotac (also Nvidia ION) it looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "nvidia"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"              "true"
        Option  "DynamicTwinView"     "false"
        Option  "FlatPanelProperties" "Scaling = Native"
        Option  "ModeValidation"      "NoVesaModes, NoXServerModes, NoVertRefreshCheck, NoHorizSyncCheck"
        Option  "UseDisplayDevice"    "DFP-1"
        Option  "ModeDebug"           "true"
    Option  "HWCursor"            "false"
EndSection
```

Comment: I installed windows 7 and all is fine now ;D